# Problema para acceder a las páginas de mi sitio despues de instalar un certificado SSL

Tags: laravel, rutas, ssl

tengo un sitio Web desarrollado en Laravel, y funcionaba bien. Acabo de instalar un certificado SSL y me funciona la ruta principal pero cuando accedo al dashboard y cualquiera de sus rutas (Es el único módulo que tiene, no tiene frontend, excepto la página principal que si funciona) me muestra un error 404.

Mis rutas están dentro de esto:

```
Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function () {

Route::group(['prefix' => 'dashboard'], function() {
```

No tengo idea que hacer para solventarlo.

Comment: Habilitaste el puerto 443?

Comment: Hola Flor, no... Cómo lo hago?

Comment: Lo hice con `Sudo ufw allow 443/tcp` y `Sudo ufw allow 443` pero no sé si es suficiente, aún no funciona

Comment: Qué estás usando Apache, Xampp, etc?

Comment: Estoy usando Apache

Comment: Entonces puedes ver este tutorial, saltarte el primer paso y pasar a la configuración del puerto. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-apache-in-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: Actualuzaste el APP_URL en el archivo .env?

Comment: No, quizás sea eso. Probará gracias!